# How to install time package for Python version 3.6

Tags: python, time, package, version, python-3.6

How to download "time" package for python 3.6. I was trying to install it for weeks but I always get the same error massage. Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: It's [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html), what do you think you need to install?

Answer (score 0):

`time` is included in the standard library. All you need to do is `import time`. I would also highly recommend updating your Python version to a more recent version like `3.10.4`.

Answer (score -1):

It's included in python’s standard library, no reason to install or download. You can just import it like so:

```
import time
```

Comment: I kinda feel stupid now. btw does it fix time.dt problem?? I wanted to add that in question too but I didn't knew how to edit it

Comment: @asdfjklč what _is_ the _"time.dt problem"_? If you want to edit, click the edit link, but note that it's bad form to change a question once it's been answered.

Comment: in my case, in Ursina engine I want to make my entity move when I press specific key. And that's all fine until this (player.x -= 4 * time.dt) it just doesn't work, or as says "cannot find refference "dt" in "time.pyi" ". Sorry for trubeling you this much